# What other headers should I be passing to Advanced Rest Client to be able to test a .js post action that requires login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http, rest

I'm using the `Advanced Rest Client` chrome extension to test some REST operations.

One action is defined as a POST member route on a `resources` entry in routes.rb . I'm passing along the `Cookie` header in the headers tab, and I'm also setting the `Accept` header to be `text/javascript, application/javascript`.

No matter what, I keep getting a `302` asking me to redirect, or a `401` error saying I need to login or authenticate before continuing.

The action has a `before_filter :authenticate_user!`, but I imagined that if I set the `Cookie` header, it would just work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to issue a correct POST request, these are the headers I've used:

```
Accept:*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript
Cache-Control:no-cache
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3000/user/5
X-CSRF-Token:0RVGFyjo7kdng8K3pUiX9b7TAoZwSNN8uUvm5wZuORk=
Cookie:your_cookie_here
```

Notice the X-CSRF-Token.

Comment: How did you get the X-CSRF-Token ?